# Show textbox value after finding it in a table row

Tags: jquery

I have many textboxes in table. All the textboxes are populated with data. I attached a keyup event handler to all textboxes and now I want to get the table row reference where the keyup event fired. My code is not working properly. I am not getting the textbox value from the `saveToLocalStore` function. Here is my code:

```
<table class="webgrid-table">
    <tr>
        <input type="text" value="Testing1"  id="Students_0__FirstName">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" value="Testing2"  id="Students_1__FirstName">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" value="Testing3"  id="Students_2__FirstName">
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]', function (ev) {
        alert($(this).val());
        var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        saveToLocalStore(tableRow);
    });
});

function saveToLocalStore(tableRow) {
    alert('ppp');
    var FirstName = tableRow.find("input[id*='FirstName']").val();
    alert(FirstName);
}
```

The `alert($(this).val());` is returning the right textbox value but the alert is not working from `saveToLocalStore`. What is the problem in the code?

Here is a jsfiddle where have replicated the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/fmdu7xbq/1/

Comment: You have invalid HTML therefore the DOM will probably be rather different than you expect it to be; the `<input>` elements may be either inside, or outside, the `<table>` and `<tr>` elements. No element other than a `<td>` or `<th>` is a valid child of a `<tr>`. In Chrome, for example, the `<input>` elements are moved ahead of the `<table>`; other browsers may react differently. To fix the problem: fix the HTML, and wrap the `<input>` elements with `<td>` or `<th>` elements.

Comment: sorry i code html in hurry and that is why there was problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid as only `td` and `th` elements can be direct children of `tr`. This means that your `input` elements are rendering outside the table, so the `find()` is not retrieving the element you expect it to. If you fix the HTML, your code works:

```
<table class="webgrid-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="Testing1" id="Students_0__FirstName">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="Testing2" id="Students_1__FirstName">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="Testing3" id="Students_2__FirstName">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hLggauda/)

Comment: sorry i code html in hurry and that is why there was problem.

Comment: in my program i did the same. onkey show the right edited value but the function which i call from onkey which is showing old value. not being able to replicate. so what could be the problem...any guess? something could be cached?

Comment: this line return old value `var FirstName = tableRow.find("input[id*='FirstName']").val();` from saveToLocalStore function.